# Scipy-Cluster installation for python 2.6

Tags: python, scipy

Has anyone used [scipy-cluster](http://code.google.com/p/scipy-cluster/) for python? I am trying to compile its source code with python 2.6 but I get some irrelevant errors. has someone had the same problem?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What OS are you using? What compiler is being used?

Comment: Pls refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412518/how-to-build-install-hcluster

Answer (score 0):

*apt-get install python-hcluster* worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: It appears the python-hcluster package is not in the newer Ubuntu version repositories. I updated my answer to provide the specific version of Ubuntu the answer applies to. It is also worth noting that python 2.6 isn't available on the newer versions of Ubuntu, thus you're looking for an answer to the wrong question.