# How to build & install hcluster?

Tags: python, hcluster

I download hcluster from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hcluster , then unzip to a folder , then type `"python setup.py install"` .  It seems OK for it shows:

```
Z:\>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_hierarchy_wrap' extension
error: None
```

But I try to "import hcluster" , it shows:

```
In [2]: import hcluster
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-002633efa200> in <module>()
----> 1 import hcluster

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\hcluster\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 import hierarchy as _h
      2 import distance as _d
      3 from hierarchy import *
      4 from distance import *
      5 from inspect import getmembers

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\hcluster\hierarchy.py in <module>()
    196
    197 import numpy as np
--> 198 import _hierarchy_wrap, types
    199 import hcluster.distance as distance
    200

ImportError: No module named _hierarchy_wrap
```

I am a newbie for building , compiling, installing etc for Python module,  can someone show a detail step how to solve this issue ? Thanks

(I am using windows XP & Python 2.6.1 )

Comment: If you have `pip`, why not use `sudo pip install hcluster` instead of manually downloading the package?

Comment: pip will not solve the problem, it just uses setup.py under the hood, it is not a magical solution that makes problem go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on windows, and are encountering a bug in distutils that prevents you from seeing the actual problem ):

```
set DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1
python setup.py ....
```

I suspect you will have something related to Visual Studio not installed. If you are using python 2.7, you need to install VS 2008, and then rerun the setup.py On python 3.x, you need a more recent version (but I am not sure whether it is 2010 or 2012 for the latest).

Another, simpler solution is to install mingw, and do::

```
python setup.py build_ext -c mingw32
```

An even simpler solution would be to check whether the feature you need are not in scipy.cluster, which has a binary installer for windows. Damian Eads (the writer of hcluster), contributed quite a bit to that module, and there is significant overlap.

Comment: I firstly "python setup.py build_ext -c mingw32", then "python setup.py bdist_wininst", then double click the generated "hcluster-0.2.0.win32-py2.6.exe", it works now. Thanks.